# Is the API for `Random.ints(origin, bound)`, `.longs(origin, bound)`, etc., missing functionality?

Tags: java, random, java-stream

It looks to me like it's impossible to include `Integer.MAX_VALUE` and `Long.MAX_VALUE` as possible random values when you create an `IntStream` or `LongStream` using bounds with the [java.util.Random](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Random.html) class.

This seems like a kind of annoying oversight. I can understand why they were trying to be consistent with the `.doubles()` version, but it makes any attempt to get a stream of random `int`s or `long`s that could include the max value (but not the full range of values, obviously, since there are methods that do that) a lot more complicated than it needs to be.

Am I missing something or has this been discussed elsewhere?

Comment: Not really clear why do you believe that ... *it's impossible to include `Integer.MAX_VALUE`*? Or what do you mean by that, can you please add a block of code to clarify that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are correct.  The javadoc states that the upper bound is exclusive.  That means that you cannot use `ints(lower, upper)` to get a stream that includes `Integer.MAX_VALUE`.

Rationale?

This is possibly an edge-case that the designers didn't consider to start with<sup>1</sup>, or that they thought was not worth a "fix" that complicated the API.

Note that `Random.nextInt(bound)` has this same problem, so this shortcoming in `Random` has been present since Java 1.2.  Therefore, another possibility is that the designers were aware of the shortcoming when they added the `ints(...)` and `longs(...)` methods, but decided not to address it because it would lead to an awkward inconsistency with the older methods.

<sup>1 - This is unlikely, IMO.  The Java team were / are smart people.  And it is clear from the source code that they are well aware of this now.</sup>

---

Anyway ... if you need streams of random numbers with a range that includes the `MAX_VALUE`s, you can use the no-args overloads (`ints()` and `longs()`) and filter the streams.  Alternatively, you could roll your own streams.

Comment: The `filter` approach isn't too awful. Thanks!